# Suppose $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is a continuous function and $\int_0^xf=\int_x^1f$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Show that $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Suppose $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function with the property that
$$\int_{0}^{x}f = \int_{x}^{1}f $$
for all $x \in [0, 1]$. Show that $f(x) = 0$ for every $x \in [0, 1]$.

I am new to such undergrad analysis, can someone please provide any hint to approach the problem, as it seems very intuitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the limit as $x \to 1$:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}f = \lim_{x \to 1}\bigg(\int_{0}^{x}f + \int_{x}^{1}f \bigg) 
$$
By continuity of $f$ we can take the limit, and the second integral equal to $0$, and so is the first, by the equality, which is valid $\forall x \in [0,1]$:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}f=\int_{1}^{1} f \equiv 0
$$
EDIT: Therefore, $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f \equiv 0 \ \forall \ x$. Using the definition of antiderivative,
$$
f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h} = \frac{0-0}{h} = 0
$$

Comment: yes! I followed the same.

Answer (score 8):

The derivative of the left side is $f(x)$ and that of the right side is $-f(x)$. Hence $f(x)=-f(x)$  and $f(x)=0$.

Comment: I am sorry, that I had some typing error in the question and have edited now, if you kindly have a look at it, it'd be grateful for me.

Comment: @PritamSarkar My answer is correct for edited version also.